# Looking for software, apps, plugins that will tile multiple images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, plugin

I am looking to use 1000 images of different people and tile them in rows and columns. I tried using the Contact Sheet II feature in Photoshop but I get white gaps between the columns. I've looked into Mosaic apps, but they require a main image and then the multiple images that will make up the main one.

I just need a grid of all the images. It seems simple but can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Would sprite sheet apps do? [Like for instance](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker). With that amount of images online tools may be out of question. Also how do you feel about command line tools?

Answer (score 1):

In "contact sheet II" you can do following tricks:

When dialog is appeared set the Image size on your need (multiply of the images in width and length in their counts of column and rows in pixel unit) after entering that values change unit to cm and set spacing values to zero, then change-back unit to pixel.
NOTE: Don't forget to uncheck "Flatten all layers" checkbox.

[image: Contact sheet II Dialog]

After your file has been made create a Solid color Layer, below all of your images like image below to hide the white borders.

[image: After and Before of Solid color in background.]